# How to change cleric domains

Tags: pathfinder-1e, cleric, religions-and-deities

Quick question, can a cleric change his domains? The domain I want to switch to is within my deity's domain list, so I don't need to switch faith.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an optional rule called [retraining](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/more-character-options/retraining) from Ultimate Combat supplement. Keep in mind that this is from supplement and this rule is **optional** even if your DM actually applies that book, so **consult your DM before using this solution.**

> #### Class Feature
>
> Many choices you make about your class features can be retrained. It takes 5 days to retrain one class feature. Training requires spending time with a character of your class **whose class level is at least 1 higher than yours** and who **has the class feature you want**. For example, if you are a 5th-level illusionist wizard and want to become a necromancer, you must train with a necromancer of at least 6th level.
>
> (...)
>
> Cleric: **Retrain one domain**; the new domain must be one granted by your deity. Doing so replaces your list of domain spells and your domain granted powers. If you are a neutral cleric of a neutral deity, you can instead retrain whether you channel positive or negative energy, which also changes whether you spontaneously cast cure spells or inflict spells.

(Excerpt from [Retraining](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/more-character-options/retraining) in Pathfinder SRD. Emphasis mine.)

So, if retraining rule is allowed, you can change your Cleric domain by retraining. To do so, you need a cleric who has the domain you desire and has more levels in Cleric than yourself. It is unclear whether the trainer must have the same faith as yourself, but I assume it is the case.

I wasn't able to find anywhere else where you can change your domain. So, I think retraining is your only call.